# re-creating WAV file

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, fft

I'm fairly new to python and to FFT, so apologies in advance - I'm trying to take a WAV file and re-create it with only certain frequencies (filter out unwanted frequencies)

I'm able to plot everything visually but am struggling to re-create a playable WAV file out of the result. 
I've minimised my problem - if I take the original signal, I can re-create the WAV file ok. 
If I run the signal through rfft and then immediately through irfft and try to re-create the WAV file from the result, the file gets created by when I try to play it (Windows 10) I get an error

> This item was encoded in a format that's not supported.

Code I'm using (reduced to bare minimum)

```
fs_rate, signal = wavfile.read(filename)
FFT = scipy.fft.rfft(signal)
recreated_signal = scipy.fft.irfft(FFT)
scipy.io.wavfile.write('recreated file1.wav',fs_rate,signal)
scipy.io.wavfile.write('recreated file2.wav',fs_rate,recreated_signal)
```

One thing I noticed is that the first file created is 5,619 KB (just under the originating file's size) whilst the second file created is 22,473 KB

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably reading in 16-bit signed integer samples and writing out 64-bit double float samples (the result of the scipy fft function), thus ending up with a file 4X larger.

Check the WAV format sample type of the original file, and compare with the vector length and numeric type of your two scipy signals.

Comment: thanks @hotpaw62, you were spot on. to be fair - I did do the conversion to int,  but I needed Int16 and not Int23.

Thanks!